# Can't use Move-Item because of process running

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-installer

and thanks to those who will read this.

I'm currently working on a Powershell to automatically retrieve metadata from MSI file and move them accordingly to these metadata. Everything is fine about getting informations, and creations of folders, but I can't get the Move-Item to work.

Windows telling me that the file can't be moved because it's used by a process.The process is powershell_ise

I'm pretty sure that this is because of the WindowsInstaller.Installer called in the beginning.

I tried several thing but couldn't make it work.

If anyone have any idea it would be gladly appreciated.
Thanks for yours time and help.

```
$folderPath = Read-Host "Please enter the path to the folder containing MSI files"
$destination = "C:\test\"

Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter *.msi | ForEach-Object {
$msi = $_.FullName

$windowsInstaller = New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer
$database = $windowsInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("OpenDatabase", 'InvokeMethod', $Null, $windowsInstaller, @($msi, 0))

$view = $database.GetType().InvokeMember("OpenView", 'InvokeMethod', $Null, $database, (@("SELECT Value FROM Property WHERE Property = 'Manufacturer'")))
$view.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", 'InvokeMethod', $Null, $view, $Null)
$record = $view.GetType().InvokeMember("Fetch", 'InvokeMethod', $Null, $view, $Null)

$manufacturer = $record.GetType().InvokeMember("StringData", 'GetProperty', $Null, $record, 1)

$view = $database.GetType().InvokeMember("OpenView", 'InvokeMethod', $Null, $database, (@("SELECT Value FROM Property WHERE Property = 'ProductName'")))
$view.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", 'InvokeMethod', $Null, $view, $Null)
$record = $view.GetType().InvokeMember("Fetch", 'InvokeMethod', $Null, $view, $Null)

$productName = $record.GetType().InvokeMember("StringData", 'GetProperty', $Null, $record, 1)

$view = $database.GetType().InvokeMember("OpenView", 'InvokeMethod', $Null, $database, (@("SELECT Value FROM Property WHERE Property = 'ProductVersion'")))
$view.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", 'InvokeMethod', $Null, $view, $Null)
$record = $view.GetType().InvokeMember("Fetch", 'InvokeMethod', $Null, $view, $Null)

$productVersion = $record.GetType().InvokeMember("StringData", 'GetProperty', $Null, $record, 1)

$destinationPath = Join-Path $destination "$manufacturer\$productName\$productVersion"

if (!(Test-Path -Path $destinationPath)) {
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $destinationPath | Out-Null
}


Move-Item $_.FullName -Destination $destinationPath
}
```

Comment: Have you tried releasing the ComObject then?

Comment: Try using parentheses: `(Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter *.msi) | Foreach-Object { ...`